# Repository Creation Utility (RCU) with SSL-enabled Oracle database

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, weblogic12c

I am trying to connect Oracle Repository Creation Utility (RCU) with SSL Enabled Oracle Database but not able to make a successful connection. I looked at the docs and online to find information on how to connect SSL enabled database with RCU Utility but no luck. How can I do this?

Comment: In general, it is better to describe your approach and _what_ is failing, rather than to ask someone to describe the whole thing. If you can show what steps you are doing that results in failure connection, someone may spot the problem you are running into.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the command-line utility in silent mode. You need to `export RCU_SSL_MODE=true` before calling the RCU utility, and then specify these additional arguments to createRepository/dropRepository:

```
-useSsl
-sslArgs oracle.net.ssl_server_dn_match=false
```

sslArgs can vary depending on what you need/want. And you're right: there doesn't seem to be any documentation about this. I had to take a look inside wls/oracle_common/jlib/rcu.jar to figure out what I needed to do.